# How do I get my age bias question reopened

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

I feel strongly that my [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75064/true-or-false-the-natural-limit-on-the-length-of-a-programming-career-is-about-2) was improperly closed. There is clearly a sharp difference of opinion on this question, but that is far different than the question being "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical". Even a moderator who closed the question took a definite position and answered the question in his/her comments. One answer that has received 14 upvotes already, so clearly people think that the question is answerable.

Is there a way to lobby to have the question reopened?

Comment: Now why was this question down voted?

Comment: Votes on meta measure agreement or disagreement with the post. A downvote in this case likely means that someone disagrees that your question was closed improperly.

Comment: I don't see how that "question" was a *question* at all.  It's a blog post with an interrogative inflection?

Answer (score 6):

This *is* the way.

You need to get 5 people with more than 3,000 reputation (or one moderator) to agree and vote to reopen.

By posting this question you've raised the profile of the question so it might be seen by enough people.

Comment: Any five people can vote to reopen?

Comment: @TGregory: Five people with more then 3k rep.